# How to exclude hadoop core jersey dependency

Tags: java, rest, maven, hadoop

I upgraded my hadoop dependencies from 1.1.1 to 0.2.0 hadoop.

Here is my problem: 
My mapreduce project depends on jersey, and hadoop 0.2.0 core depends on an older version of jersey.
So a method in my mapreduce classes leads to "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap.addAll"

As a Solution: 
In the pom file, I excluded jersey from hadoop dependency, but this still didn't solve the overall problem

When I try running a class with the function (that used to lead to error) as java, now it works. However when I try to run it with hadoop command it keeps giving me same error.

Comment: I don't think what you are asking for is possible, not unless you can somehow separate the ClassLoader.  Basically, you are asking to have to versions of the same .class.

Comment: when you run hadoop command what classpath it takes in consideration, as a hack you can change the order of library in classpath to give priority to wanted jar

Comment: You may still have multiple versions of the library on your classpath at build time. I have seen it where eclipse dependency viewer and maven dependency tree do not show you the dependency but when you package your artifact, you notice multiple versions in the lib directory.

These errors are almost always caused by multiple versions of the same class on your classpath.

Comment: Could you please update the question with the output of mvn dependency:tree